# How to determine if Vista "Platform Update Supplement" is installed on the target machine?

Tags: inno-setup, windows-vista

My application requires a minimum target machine of Vista+Sp2+KB2117917. The latter is also called "Platform Update Supplement" and should have really been called SP3.
How can Inno Setup determine whether it is installed or not?

Comment: Write a DLL that can check for that and use this with Inno Setup

Comment: @Sir Rufo Thanks. I wander if there isn't a more fundamental way such as a  system call or registry entry.

Comment: There is and therefore you need the DLL -> [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387101(v=vs.85).aspx)